# SSRS Reports transferred to different server

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I have several SSRS reports that need to be transferred to another server. Currently, all reports and SSRS reside on the same exact server as SSMS and all databases. I was wondering if there is a simple way to essentially take everything I have on SSRS (All Reports) and transfer them along with their data sources to the new server that I have. I know downloading all reports and uploading them to the new server is an option but I was wondering if their is an easier/more logical way to go about this process. After completion, SSRS and the SQL Server will be on different servers but still able to work together.

Answer (score 0):

I have had really great experiences with an old (2007) program called "SSRS Scripter" (from Jasper Smith).  It seems like it has been absorbed into a newer product called SqlServerFineBuild (which I have never used). The original stuff is a little hard to find, but very nice to work-with, imo.

Microsoft also has another product called Reporting Services Migration Tool (free) https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29560 It is a command-line util and isn't the easiest or most-helpful.  It has a UI-mode, but it isn't very user-friendly.

Both of these will only extract report files and settings from an existing site. You still need to use VStudio (+ reporting add-in) (and then some RS project work/design/config) to re-deploy.

Comment: Thanks for responding! Do you know if that 2007 tool still works? Thanks.

Comment: I have used SSRS scripter on SSRS up-to SQL 2008R2 (eq, 2010).